# Standard Score or z-score

Tags: statistics

On the first periodic exam in Statistics, the population mean was 70 and the population standard deviation was 9. How to determine the standard score of a student who got a score of 88 assuming that the scores are normally distribtued?

Answer (score 1):

We can use 
$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \Rightarrow Z=\frac{88-70}{9}=2$$